# How to restore the global application menu for Chromium Browser?

Tags: chromium, appmenu

I lost it since I've added the daily updates PPA , and installed the progress bar for downloads. And now I've removed the Daily updates PPA, and installed Chromium from the software Center but Global Menu doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chromium type `about:flags` in the address bar. There should be an item "Enable experimental GNOME menubar". Be sure to hit "restart" at the bottom of the page.

Comment: ohh I see , thx